# Локация для программы .SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, app, location

В программе считываю файл. Как я могу  подстроится под локацию на телефоне ?

Пример того что должно быть.

```
  let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]

    if  preferredLanguage == "en"{

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "predictENG", ofType: "txt")
    }else if preferredLanguage == "ru"{
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "predictRUS", ofType: "txt")
    }
}
```

Comment: Да , это что я хочу использовать, просто не очень понимаю как именно это сделать в коде

Comment: [вот](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization), пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

1. Всё взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591167/how-to-get-current-language-code-with-swift)
2. Что бы узнать язык **приложения**: `let pre = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]`
3. Что бы узнать язык **устройства**: `let locale =  Locale.current.languageCode`

Comment: Мне нужно задать как то эту локаль. (if local == eng) мне нужно именно эту строку как то реализовать .

Comment: @GlebSeredyuk Прошу прощения, но что вы имеете ввиду под "задать эту локаль"? Задать на устройстве? Это делается через настройки. Если вы говорите про `== eng`, то для этих целей служат короткие имена языков (ru, de, gr и т.д.).

Comment: Я обновил свой код, смотрите пожалуйста. Нужно в условии сделать проверку, если на устройстве язык английский то считать файл fileENG , если язык русский, то считать fileRUS

Answer (score 0):

Вот что я сделал.

```
let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]

        if  preferredLanguage == "ru"{

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileRUS", ofType: "txt")

        }else {
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileENG", ofType: "txt")

            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        }
```